# What is the "kind" of a resource in Azure ARM Templates?

Tags: azure, azure-arm-template

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/serverfarms?tabs=json#serverfarms

The only documentation about that property of the ARM Template is this:

[image]

That description is not helpful at all, and I couldn't find any examples of it anywhere. I thought it referred to the type of resource as in `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms`, but that's what the `type` property is for.

Answer (score 1):

Not an official answer, but helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62400396/100596

Copied from source:

`api` - api app

`app` - windows web app

`app,linux` - linux web app

`functionapp` - windows function app

`functionapp,linux` - linux function app

`container` - containerized

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `@Alan McBee`s answer is wrong, the list is refering to App Services (`Microsoft.Web/sites`) and not App Service Plans (`Microsoft.Web/serverfarms`), and also is not complete (see linked question, not the accepted answer).

The `kind` property for the App Service Plan has no meaning.

> Note that the kind property also shows up in App Service Plans (ASP). At this time, the value of this property for the ASP is meaningless and has no impact on your resource. For example, you can set kind to “Linux” for the ASP, but that won’t make your ASP a Linux ASP; the reserved property is what makes this distinction (if reserved = true, it’s a Linux ASP, otherwise it’s a Windows ASP).

See 2nd to last paragraph here:
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/08/31/Kind-property-overview.html